# Single Server SP2019 Farm - Site Loads IIS Splash Screen

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, iis, dns

I've completed an installation of a single server SP2019 farm with AD, DHCP & DNS.

Central Admin loads perfectly fine and I can create new Content DB's and Site Collections.

I've correctly configured the registry here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\MSV1_0\BackConnectionHostNames
```

and here:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\DisableLoopbackCheck
```

I'm connected to the server via RDP, however I can't load any sites that I've created. When I browse to any sites (including the default root site) I get the IIS splash screen:

[image]

Here are my IIS bindings:

[image]

I've setup these single server farms many times in the great before and I remember there were a few caveats about loading sites on the single server instance.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a lack of disk space and memory on the VM. This played havoc with the setup process.

Initially during the SharePoint/SQL installation I had only 30gb of disk space and 4gb RAM.

I created a new VM with adequate storage and memory and started from scratch. Everything now works perfectly!

Comment: Not the most obvious reason )

Comment: No that's what had me scratching my head. But i suppose it's documented now so...

Answer (score 1):

You can check these:

- In `IIS`, stop the `Default Web Site`
- Check the `bindings` URL of the site corresponding to your SharePoint web application
- Check the `alternate access mapping` in the Central Administration (System Settings > Configure alternate access mappings)
- If you use custom DNS, you can edit the host file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`) to add something like that:

  `127.0.0.1 my-new-webapp.dev.local`

Comment: Thanks for responding! None of these steps worked for me. I've edited the post to include my IIS bindings.

Comment: But where is your web application? I don’t see it in IIS. This is not the default web site. What about your host name and AAM?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't created any Web Application in Central Admin.

It is better to change *Default Web Site* **http** binding from port 80 to smth else (like 8888) and leave it enabled.

Then you should create the Web Application and you'll be fine.